# Как сохранить данные полученные во время диалога с ботом? (PyTelegramBotAPI)

Tags: python, sqlite3, telebot

```
import telebot
from telebot import types
import sqlite3
import config
import time

#bot
bot = telebot.TeleBot(config.token)

@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start(message):
    #head

    global connect
    global cursor

    connect = sqlite3.connect('shop_base.db')
    cursor = connect.cursor()

    cursor.execute('''CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS info(
        item BIGINT,
        phone_number TEXT
        )''')
    connect.commit()

    #body
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Доброго времени суток! Вы попали в магазин "тохтик". Сегодня у нас всё на халяву, заказывайте.')
    
    markup_1 = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)

    btn1 = types.KeyboardButton('Вкусный тохтик')
    btn2 = types.KeyboardButton('Невкусный тохтик')
    btn3 = types.KeyboardButton('Пельмень')
    btn4 = types.KeyboardButton('Много пельменей')

    markup_1.add(btn1)
    markup_1.add(btn2)
    markup_1.add(btn3)
    markup_1.add(btn4)

    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Что вы хотите заказать?', reply_markup=markup_1)
    @bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
    def get_item(message):
        registered = 'Понял, принял, записал.'
        if message.chat.type == 'private':
            if message.text == 'Вкусный тохтик':
                global add1
                add1 = 'Вкусный тохтик'
                time.sleep(1)
                bot.send_message(message.chat.id, registered)
            if message.text == 'Невкусный тохтик':
                global add2
                add2 = 'Невкусный тохтик'
                time.sleep(1)
                bot.send_message(message.chat.id, registered)
            if message.text == 'Пельмень':
                global add3
                add3 = 'Пельмень'
                time.sleep(1)
                bot.send_message(message.chat.id, registered)
            if message.text == 'Много пельменей':
                global add4
                add4 = 'Много пельменей'
                time.sleep(1)
                bot.send_message(message.chat.id, registered)
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Напишите свой номер телефона:')
            ph_number = message.text
            print(ph_number)

#run
bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```

Comment: Уже ответили на этот вопрос https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1176757/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%83-%D0%B2-telegram-%D0%BD%D0%B0-python

Answer (score 0):

Надо использовать register_next_step_handler первый аргумент - сообщение с вопросом, второй - какую функцию хотите вызвать.
Более подробный ответ по этой теме - ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1282213/234134