# Как скачать фотографии и файлы ботом телеграмм , без дополнительных выборов?

Tags: python, telegram, telebot, бот

Имею такой код:

```
  @bot.message_handler(content_types=['document'])
    def handle_docs_photo(message):
        try:
            chat_id = message.chat.id
            if message == photo:
                file_info = bot.get_file(message.photo[len(message.photo) - 1].file_id)
                downloaded_file = bot.download_file(file_info.file_path)
                src = 'D:/MYSOR Z TG/' + file_info.file_path
            elif message == document:
                file_info = bot.get_file(message.document.file_id)
                downloaded_file = bot.download_file(file_info.file_path)
                src = 'D:/MYSOR Z TG/' + message.document.file_name;
            with open(src, 'wb') as new_file:
                new_file.write(downloaded_file)
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Saved')
            time.sleep(3)
            bot.delete_message(message.chat.id, message.message_id)
        except Exception as e:
            bot.reply_to(message, e)
```

Ошибка возникает в самом телеграмме (в консоли все чисто):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Использовал методы отсюда:[https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1176757/Как-получить-файл-присланный-пользователем-боту-в-telegram-на-python](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1176757/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%83-%D0%B2-telegram-%D0%BD%D0%B0-python)

Как нормально объединить их?

Comment: Ошибка не в телеграм, а в переменной `photo`, которая не объявлена. Вместо `if message == photo:` - `if message.content.type == 'photo':`

Comment: 'Message' object has no attribute 'content' и 'Message' object has no attribute 'type' , кинуть весь код?

Comment: `message.content_type`

Comment: Да! Теперь скачивает файлики, но фото(сжатое) не скачивает.