# Как реализовать получение файла от пользователя pyTelegramBotAPI?

Tags: python, python-3.x, telebot

Искал много информации по этому поводу. В ответ нашёл только документацию

```
# getFile
# Downloading a file is straightforward
# Returns a File object
import requests
file_info = tb.get_file(file_id)

file = requests.get('https://api.telegram.org/file/bot{0}/{1}'.format(API_TOKEN, file_info.file_path))
```

Comment: на этот вопрос уже есть ответ, ссылка ниже https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1176757/Как-получить-файл-присланный-пользователем-боту-в-telegram-на-python

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как получить файл присланный пользователем боту в Telegram на python?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1176757/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc-%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d1%83-%d0%b2-telegram-%d0%bd%d0%b0-python)